# compactness of fractional Sobolev spaces

Tags: reference-request, fa.functional-analysis

I am looking for a reference on the paper on compact Sobolev embeddings.
If we define the Sobolev space $$X_{0}(A):=\{u\in H^s(\mathbb R^N): u=0\quad \text{in}\quad \mathbb R^N \setminus A\}$$ where $A$ is an annulus and $s\in(0, 1)$.

Is it true that the class of radial functions in $X_{0}(A)$  is compact in $L^p(A)$ for any $p>1?$

Comment: What do you assume about $s$? The answer depends on that.

Comment: Thanks for pointing me out. It should be between 0 and 1.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have the compact embedding of radial Sobolev functions in $X_0(A)$ to $L^p(A)$ for all $1\leq p<\infty$ if and only if $s\geq 1/2$.

The proof goes as follows.

A radial function $F(x)$ on the annulus $A=\{ a<|x|<b\}$ is a function of the form $F(x)=f(|x|)$ for some $f$ defined on the interval $(a,b)$. Now $F\in L^p$ iff $f\in L^p(a,b)$ and $F_k\to F$ in $L^p$ iff $f_k\to f$ in $L^p(a,b)$ by Fubini's theorem. Also  $F\in X_0(A)$ iff $f\in H^s_0(a,b)$,
Therefore compact embedding of radial functions in $X_0(A)$ to all $L^p$, $1\leq p<\infty$ is equivalent to compact embedding of $H^s_0(a,b)$ to $L^p(a,b)$ for all $1\leq p<\infty$. This however, is true when $s\geq 1/2$. Just check the textbooks that discuss compactness of embedding of $H^s$. I do not have a right reference on top of my head.

Comment: Your answer is correct. Thanks for the idea.

Comment: I already did so.

Comment: @sadiaz You voted my question up, but you did not accept it. To accept the answer you click on the V sign which becomes green after that.